# AVX: matrix dot vector, but ignore diagonal

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I need to perform a dot product between a square matrix, and a vector. However, the diagonal must always be ignored during this particular operation. I am doing this with AVX.

How can I modify my existing code to efficiently ignore all the [i,i] places, so that it's remains cache-friendly?

```
template<bool add_to_result=false>
inline void dot( const float *const f_vecStart,  size_t fVecCount,  float *result ) const {
    m2d_assert(fVecCount == _y);
    assert_is_16_aligned(f_vecStart);
    assert_is_16_aligned(result);

    float *f_rowStart = _matArray;
    float *f_rowEnd = _matArray + _y;

    for (size_t i=0; i<_x; ++i){ //for every row:
        const __m256 *a = (__m256*)f_rowStart;
        const __m256 *rowEnd = (__m256*)(f_rowEnd);
        const __m256 *val_vec = (__m256*)(f_vecStart);

        __m256 mRowSum = _mm256_set1_ps(0.0f);

        while(a<rowEnd){
            __m256 mul = _mm256_mul_ps(*a, *val_vec);
            mRowSum = _mm256_add_ps(mRowSum, mul);

            ++val_vec;  ++a;
        }

        // finally, horizontally add the gathered sum (m256 vector), completing the
        // computation for this entire row:
        if (add_to_result){//<--known at compile time.
            result[i] += Mathf::fast_hAdd_ps(mRowSum);
        }
        else {
            result[i] = Mathf::fast_hAdd_ps(mRowSum);//<--notice EQUALS (overwrite garbage values)
        }

        f_rowStart += _y;
        f_rowEnd += _y;
    }//end for every row

    check_isNan(result, _x);
}
```

Comment: Add another pointer `const __m256 *skip_me = a + i * sizeof(a)`, then skip the operation in your `while(a<rowEnd)` if `a == skip_me`.

Comment: You could temporarily make the appropriate source vector element `0.0`, if it's not `const`.  That will "only" cause store-forwarding stalls in the first few elements; later ones should have time for the scalar store to leave the store buffer before vector reload.  Otherwise you could split the inner loop into two ranges, but that might mispredict.  BTW, you might want to accumulate 2 or 4 rows in parallel, unrolling the loop to hide FP add latency and giving you room to shuffle-and-hadd in the cleanup.  (But that's a problem for modifying the actual source vector).

Comment: @John: and how are you going to make *that* efficient?  You mean with a branch?  You can't just skip the whole `__m256`, you need to do the other 7 elements that aren't on the diagonal.

Comment: @Peter I dunno man. Efficient is subjective. I also don't know what AVX or an __m256 are, so take that for what it's worth.

Comment: @John AVX are vector operations. __m256 are 256 bytes filled with a bunch of values of the used type, in this case floats. So skipping single elements really doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you should formulate your comment as an answer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: done.  There might be a better idea I haven't thought of, but yeah that's enough of an idea to put in an answer.

Comment: How large is your matrix? Is it always a multiple of 8? Do you have FMA? Generally, you should add 8 rows simultaneously to avoid FMA latency, but also reduce number of loads of your vector. If your vector is very large (larger than L1 cache), consider working in blocks. Regarding the diagonal, I'd split the inner loop into the parts before and after the diagonal, and make some special treatment for the diagonal 8x8 block (e.g., use `vblendps` to blend out the diagonal).

Comment: @chtz Thank you! Could you please make your comment into answer. Please provide me a code, showing how to simultaniously add the 8 rows, it would really help me. But wouldn't this require us to grab from 8 different matrix rows, thus ruining the cache performance?

Comment: @Kari Could you answer my questions first? Accessing the matrix non-linearly likely has less cost impact than having to read the vector only 1/8 as often (really depends on the size of your matrix, your cache sizes, etc)

Comment: @chtz, So the matrix is 1024x1024 and the vector is 1024. Indeed, I always check for multiple of 8, and 16-byte alignment is guaranteed. I think FMA is supported (AMD 8350 cpu)

Comment: If wikipedia is correct, that should be a Piledriver and support FMA. I'll work out an answer (maybe not today, though). Btw: If possible, for AVX you should try to guarantee 32byte alignment (although the impact of unaligned loads is not as big as it used to be).

Comment: @chtz: cache blocking only helps if you have multiple mat*vec products to do with different vectors (in which case it's great).  A single mat*vec product touches each matrix element only once, no data reuse for cache to help with.  (And the access pattern is contiguous along rows)

Answer (score 3):

If the FP rounding error isn't a problem, you can of course just subtract `vec[i] * matrow[i]` from that dot product, after the loop.  But that fails if it results in a NaN or Inf, or a huge number that results in huge rounding error for the rest of the dot product.

---

For small matrices, you could consider adding some kind of branchless masking to the inner loop.  e.g. a vector of {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} that you increment with `+=8`, and vpcmpeqd against `set1_epi32(i)`.  Use that as a mask with ANDN.

For large matrices, you want something that only adds overhead to the outer loop, not the inner-most loop.

You could temporarily make the appropriate source vector element `0.0`, if it's not `const`. That will "only" cause store-forwarding stalls in the first few rows; later ones should have time for the scalar store to leave the store buffer before vector reload reaches that point.  (Especially if you do it as early as possible, like before the hsum of the previous row.)

Of course if you can zero the matrix diagonal, that works too.  But much worse spatial locality for those stores.  (Doing it right before reading that row would be the least bad for locality on large matrices)

Otherwise you could split the inner loop into two ranges, using a vector mask for the one vector that spans the diagonal.  That might introduce some branch misprediction.  If you're parallelizing and running on a hyperthreaded machine, SMT can maintain throughput.  Otherwise you'd have to hope it predicts well.

BTW, you might want to accumulate 2 to 8 rows in parallel, unrolling the loop to hide FP add latency and giving you room to shuffle-and-hadd in the cleanup.  A transpose-and-sum of 4 or 8 vectors is cheaper than 8x hsums down to a single vector.  (But that's a problem for modifying the actual source vector).

---

I haven't tested any of these; this is just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a `vblendps` on the multiplication result for the diagonal blocks. This is very easy when unrolling 8 loop iterations. By unrolling, you also save reloading your vector every time. Afterwards, just multiply+add the remaining blocks to that (with FMA, if available). And finally reduce the vector results to a single vector (this is one of the few cases where `haddps` can be beneficial).

Here is a version which assumes that your size is a multiple of 8 (and your matrix is square). It either adds to the existing vector in `result` or "adds" to an implicit zero vector. I added `_matArray` as function parameter and I assume `_x`, `_y` and `fVecCount` are all the same in your example. Un-tested/benchmarked (["but it compiles"](https://godbolt.org/z/6DxBVM)) and quite a lot of copy+paste code (you can try to have a compiler auto-unroll parts of that).
Regarding cache-locality it might be better to just unroll 4 rows (8*1024*4B = 32KiB, which is larger than L1 cache of a Piledriver). Or maybe adding some prefetches helps as well.

```
void dot(float* result, float const* _matArray, float const* f_vecStart) {
  bool const add_to_result = true; // can also be a template parameter
  int const rowlength = 1024;      // can also be a function parameter
  for (int row = 0; row < rowlength; row += 8) {
    float const* blockStart = _matArray + rowlength * row;
    // registers for accumulation
    __m256 s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7;

    // calculate diagonal-block:
    {
      // register to blend out or replace value by pre-existing value
      __m256 res0 = add_to_result ? _mm256_loadu_ps(result + row) : _mm256_setzero_ps();

      __m256 vec_r = _mm256_loadu_ps(f_vecStart + row);
      s0 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 0 * rowlength));
      s1 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 1 * rowlength));
      s2 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 2 * rowlength));
      s3 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 3 * rowlength));
      s4 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 4 * rowlength));
      s5 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 5 * rowlength));
      s7 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 7 * rowlength));
      s6 = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + row + 6 * rowlength));

      // replace diagonal product by zero or pre-existing result value
      s0 = _mm256_blend_ps(s0, res0, 1 << 0);
      s1 = _mm256_blend_ps(s1, res0, 1 << 1);
      s2 = _mm256_blend_ps(s2, res0, 1 << 2);
      s3 = _mm256_blend_ps(s3, res0, 1 << 3);
      s4 = _mm256_blend_ps(s4, res0, 1 << 4);
      s5 = _mm256_blend_ps(s5, res0, 1 << 5);
      s6 = _mm256_blend_ps(s6, res0, 1 << 6);
      s7 = _mm256_blend_ps(s7, res0, 1 << 7);
    }

    // add remaining elements
    for (int col = 0; col < rowlength; col += 8) {
      // skip diagonal block. Maybe it is worth splitting the loop into two halves
      if (col == row) continue;

      __m256 vec_r = _mm256_loadu_ps(f_vecStart + col);
      s0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 0 * rowlength), s0);
      s1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 1 * rowlength), s1);
      s2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 2 * rowlength), s2);
      s3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 3 * rowlength), s3);
      s4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 4 * rowlength), s4);
      s5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 5 * rowlength), s5);
      s6 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 6 * rowlength), s6);
      s7 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(vec_r, _mm256_loadu_ps(blockStart + col + 7 * rowlength), s7);
    }

    // reduce s0-s7 horizontally and store
    {
      // Perhaps on Piledriver doing vshufps+blend is more efficient?
      __m256 s01 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s0, s1);
      __m256 s23 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s2, s3);
      __m256 s45 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s4, s5);
      __m256 s67 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s6, s7);

      __m256 s0123 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s01, s23);
      __m256 s4567 = _mm256_hadd_ps(s45, s67);

      // inter-lane reduction
      // combine upper half of s0123 with lower half of s4567:
      __m256 res = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(s0123, s4567, 0x21);
      // blend lower half of s0123 with upper half of s4567 and add:
      res = _mm256_add_ps(res, _mm256_blend_ps(s0123, s4567, 0xF0));

      // store result. Ideally, replace by store_ps, if you can guarantee 32byte alignment
      _mm256_storeu_ps(result + row, res);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For Piledriver specifically: _mm256_hadd_ps sucks extra for some reason (8 uops: 4 per 128-bit lane instead of the 6 (3 per lane) you'd expect for 2x vshufps to feed a vertical add).  On Zen1 even 128-bit `hadd` is 4 uops, but not so on Piledriver (https://agner.org/optimize). Also, 256-bit stores have a big throughput bug, but even on Steamroller and Zen1 you'd want to avoid the final vperm2f128 lane-crossing shuffle and just extract high halves (vextractf128) for 128-bit adds / vector stores. This code should be good on Intel, though, or Zen2 where `vhaddps` ymm is 3 uops, vs. 4 for xmm (?!)

Comment: re: how much to unroll: you only touch each matrix element once; There's no temporal locality, only spatial. It's really a question of how many input streams you want to have  (And possible conflict misses if the row stride is a large power of 2).  You could still unroll by 8 but with 2 accumulators per row (which you sum vertically outside the loop, before hsum).  Then only 4 of the 8 initializers need a blend, I think.